# convert HTML into word in .net application

Tags: sql, .net, xml, openxml

Can anyone suggest how to show value stored in SQL in HTML form to word file. I am using open xml  tool to  generate my word from my asp.net MVC application and it works fine but now I am stuck in one point where there is a bullet points entry stored in my DB field and I have to show it in my table cell text property?

actual value stored in DB field:  `"<ul><li>tapan</li><li>gupta</li></ul><p>&nbsp;</p>"`

```
Run run362 = new Run();

        RunProperties runProperties358 = new RunProperties();
        RunFonts runFonts851 = new RunFonts() { Hint = FontTypeHintValues.EastAsia, Ascii = "Helvetica", HighAnsi = "Helvetica", ComplexScript = "Arial" };
        FontSize fontSize833 = new FontSize() { Val = "20" };
        Languages languages772 = new Languages() { EastAsia = "zh-HK" };

        runProperties358.Append(runFonts851);
        runProperties358.Append(fontSize833);
        runProperties358.Append(languages772);
        Text text299 = new Text() { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };

        text299.Text = **my field value**    

        run362.Append(runProperties358);
        run362.Append(text299);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Html to Open XML.

Refer Here : http://html2openxml.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps!